# Obstacle problems for minimal hypersurfaces

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, geometric-measure-theory

Given a compact Riemannian $n+1$-manifold $M$ **with (possibly not mean convex) boundary** (smooth or probably with codim $>2$ singularities). Consider the following problems,

1) fix a homology class $\alpha \in H_n(M, \mathbb{Z})$ and minimize $n-1$ volume among all integral cycles supported in $M$ and homologous to $\alpha$ ;

2) fix an integral cycle supported in the boundary, and solve (oriented or not) Plateau problem supported in $M$,

3) find min-max solutions in both settings (prescribe boundary or not) above

Can we find hypersurface with promising regularity (e.g. smooth outside a codimension 7 subset in the interior of $M$ and $C^{1,1}$ when hit the boundary), as solutions to above problems in $M$ ?